# How do I punctuate this sentence? A machine breaks down on average three times per day

Tags: punctuation

I am confused about whether it should be

> A machine breaks down - on average - three times per day.

or

> A machine breaks down on average, three times per day.

Comment: How about two commas?

Comment: Maybe: "On average, a machine breaks down three times per day." Or "A machine breaks down three times per day on average"?

Comment: ... Yes, I prefer @Jules's way of _writing_ it, but your way would be common in speech. As Isabel implies, << on average >> is essentially a parenthetical, needing the same setting off at each end. I'd say dashes (**not** hyphens) are too heavy-duty here, and brackets would only be appropriate if there were some reason to emphasise the averaging involved (unlikely). Commas are lightweight enough, indicating short pauses in speech. I'd choose zero punctuation at each end here as I'd leave no pauses in enunciating – this is a rare example where zero punctuation around a parenthetical works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of brackets/parentheses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100603/usage-of-brackets-parentheses)

Comment: No commas are required. "On average" and "three times per day" are sufficiently integrated into the clause as to not require their boundaries to be marked by punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

No punctuation is necessary. You can swap in a different adverb to see:

> *A machine breaks down about three times per day.*

Here are some more examples of *on average* in action:

[Corpus of Contemporary American English: on average](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=87939646)

If you want to make *on average* nonessential—an aside—then use punctuation (commas, em dashes, parentheses) on both sides of it:

> *A machine breaks down, on average, three times per day.*