# Two commas in sentence

Tags: punctuation, end-punctuation

This is probably quite basic, but I can't think what it's called!

What is this 'rule' called, i.e. where you need two commas to separate this piece from 'they,' and finishing 'others,' from the rest of the sentence?  I need to know the formal name/rule.

*It provides a place in which they, working together with parents and others, can gain a sense of achievement and which enables them to influence their lives and their own cultures.*

Don't shout at me for using the word 'rule', please!

Comment: The part set off with commas is parenthetical, i.e., you could do away with it, without rendering the rest of the sentence meaningless. It just provides extra information.

Comment: Parenthetical without necessarily adding a parenthesis?

Comment: Parentheticals may be set off by commas, dashes, parentheses, zero punctuation on the odd occasion, or even ellipses. More information at the duplicate I've added, and you can search for other threads looking at 'parentheses' / 'parentheticals'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of brackets/parentheses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100603/usage-of-brackets-parentheses)

Comment: Amazing, thank you Edwin.  What is 'zero punctuation'?