# Comma use after imperative verb form

Tags: commas

Is there a difference between the two sentences in meaning or syntactical correctness?

Analyze, in your own words, the difference between the authors.

and

Analyze in your own words the difference between the authors.

Comment: Why not..."In your own words, analyze..."

Comment: The only difference is that the comma offsetting of the PP adds emphasis to the parenthetical addition, almost as bolding would. Brackets and dashes are other options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of brackets/parentheses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100603/usage-of-brackets-parentheses), where 'I have decided that if it is sunny tomorrow I will go to the park.' and variants are discussed. The imperative in today's example is a red herring.