# Do you need a comma at the end of an insert?

Tags: commas

I have read some documents and saw two versions:

> We certify that Joe Doe, born on the 1st of January 2000, attended something.
>
> We certify that Joe Doe, born on the 1st of January 2000 attended something.

Are both correct?

Comment: "born on the 1st of January 2000" is a "parenthetical", and requires commas at both ends (unless there's a period instead).

Comment: Well yes it makes sense but I thought comma rules in English are somewhat flexible enough that maybe both versions are grammatically correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of brackets/parentheses (etc)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100603/usage-of-brackets-parentheses-etc) Medial parentheticals require balanced offsetting punctuation, whether two ellipses, two dashes, two commas, a pair of brackets, or zero punctuation at each end.

Answer (score 1):

We certify that Joe Doe, born on the 1st of January 2000, attended something. Correct

We certify that Joe Doe, born on the 1st of January 2000 attended something. Incorrect

The portion between the commas in the first example is information that can be omitted without changing the meaning of the sentence, and for that reason it needs the commas. Think dependent/independent clause relationship.