# Comma usage and "for"

Tags: meaning, commas, nuance

Here are three examples collected from the Internet:

> (1) Teslamotors.com **is for many, the** first introduction to Tesla and EVs. *(one-comma version)*

> (2) This last point **is, for many, the** most important for those tasked with making decisions for the recently deceased. *(two-comma version)*

> (3) SU's website **is for many the** first experience and interaction with the university. *(commaless version)*

Apparently, all of the three examples are mutually equivalent in terms of structure and semantics. I am not sure whether they really mean the same since I have found an author used the two-comma version in juxtaposition with the one-comma version:

> If writing **was, for Shi Tiesheng, a** way to avoid suicidal thoughts, it **is for many prominent
> thinkers in the urban intellectual Christian circles, a** vocation.

Do they have subtle difference or it is simply a stylistic choice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first is non-standard. Offsetting 'for many' with commas signals 'pauses for thought' and is completely at the discretion of the writer. Arguably, using two offsetting commas helps with parsing and some would thus prefer offsetting the parenthetical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of brackets/parentheses (etc)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100603/usage-of-brackets-parentheses-etc). Note that 'for many' is just one example of many possible parentheticals here (after all / in any case / in most cases / one might argue / on the other hand ...).