# Where to put breath breaks in

Tags: pronunciation

> But along the way they may just find out that by analyzing why
> something went horribly wrong, they’ve learned a lot.

Source: https://www.snexplores.org/article/really-learn-fail-then-fail-again

When you read aloud the above sentence, where would you put breath breaks in, if any? I think that your first option would be at the comma (ie after the word "wrong"). Would you ever put a breath break in after the word "that"? Or before that?

I hope that this kind of question will be accepted in this section of the forum. I would greatly appreciate it if you could kindly enlighten me.

Comment: I'd use one after the introductory "But along the way, they ..."

Comment: Thank you. Now, would you ever put a breath pause before or after the word "that" in the sentence?

Comment: I'd use either zero commas or two to offset 'by analyzing why something went horribly wrong'. But Yosef's suggestion of a comma to offset the introductory 'along the way' is good; there doesn't need to be a comma after 'But', and one wants to avoid clutter. I wouldn't use over two commas, and prefer the comma after 'way' to the one after 'wrong' if a single comma is opted for.

Comment: This kind of thing depends on the speaker and the situation. A fast speaker may need fewer breaks. If you're speaking while exhausted, while sleepy, while jogging, etc., you will need more breath breaks and you will naturally insert more pauses.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming no physical effort (that is: you read not while recovering from a fast run or similar) one breathes about once every 2-3 seconds. Reading the above sentence aloud took me approximately 10 seconds, which in turn means that I breathe about 3-4 times reading it.

Also notice that there is a difference between reading written text and hearing spoken text. When reading you can go back and re-read, but you cannot re-hear. Therefore speakers tend to overpronounce if they want their auditory to get everything they say.

Now, let us split up the sentence into word-groups which belong together:

> But
> along the way
> they may just find out
> that
> by analyzing
> why something went horribly wrong,
> they’ve learned a lot.

There you have it. The ends of the lines are the possible places for breathing because emphasizing what belongs together is usually done by inserting a small pause anyway. Like this:

> ... they may find out - that - by analyzing ...

You do not need to use all of these part-endings for breathing and you may skip some of the (for lack of a better word) "syntactical breaks", but in general these are the places to put them (if any at all).

Comment: But / along the way / ...

Comment: I'd keep *by analyzing why* together but that's just preference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: you are right, thank you. I have adapted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a comma after "way", but often, people don't use one. In rare cases they use a comma after "but" and one after "way". ([but along the way](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but%20along%20the%20way%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

You *never* use a comma after or before "that" when "that" is a conjunction. (This the case of the sentence in the OP.)

- The student said that he would come.

As a relative pronoun, "that" cannot be nonrestrictive, and so you *never* use a comma after or before "that" when it is a relative pronoun. (You always use a comma before a pronoun that is nonrestrictive, but only "who", "whom", "which" and "whose" can be nonrestrictive.)

- The house that you see over there is for sale. (*restrictive*)
- The shopkeeper, whose shop had not been open for weeks, was poor. (*nonrestrictive*)

*Additions following comments*

*[User Stuart](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611594/where-to-put-breath-breaks-in/611603?noredirect=1#comment1549811_611603), comparison with 19th century English, in* Ivanhoe

Today some of these commas would not be used; for instance, in "from which it may be inferred, that it was put on by slipping it…" ([*Ivanhoe*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Ivanhoe/zzQJAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)) no comma is used. "It seemed to be your opinion, that" (*Ivanhoe*) would not be written with a comma nowadays ([it's their opinion that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s%20their%20opinion%20that%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)). There are nevertheless in *Ivanhoe* uses of the comma before "that" that are still valid, but they are the exception to the rule; they do not occur in simple constructions.  "Rely on this, that…" (*Ivanhoe*) is still written with a comma nowadays,  but that is not the plain construction. There is then the case of the introduction of adverbs;  the "I am conscious, however, that the slight, unsatisfactory, and …" in *Ivanhoe* should today still be written in the exact same way, but this is not the plain construction. It would be an error today to write "I am conscious, that…". Introducing "first" in the "inferred" construction above makes the comma valid today ([inferred, first, that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inferred%20first%20that%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)); I don't think it is necessary though, it is rather optional.

*[User Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611594/where-to-put-breath-breaks-in/611603?noredirect=1#comment1549812_611603)
, alternative modern point of view*

The reader might be interested in considering that the term "conjunction" used above is not considered proper in modern linguistics, in which  the idea is put forward that this word is not a conjunction; the details as to the demonstration of this fact will have to sought in the literature on the subject.

> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer)) In linguistics (especially generative grammar), a **complementizer** or **complementiser** (glossing abbreviation: comp) is a functional category (part of speech) that includes those words that can be used to turn a clause into the subject or object of a sentence. For example, the word "that" may be called a complementizer in English sentences like "Mary believes **that** it is raining". The concept of complementizers is specific to certain modern grammatical theories. In traditional grammar, such words are normally considered conjunctions. The standard abbreviation for complementizer is **C**.

Comment: You don't use a comma before or after "that" in modern English, but I think that's more an arbitrary rule than anything else. A short pause before "that" when speaking is common. Picking a 19th century text at random, commas before "that" are frequent in Scott's [Ivanhoe](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Ivanhoe/zzQJAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover), from the Advertisement onward ("It was the author's intention, that this work...").

Comment: 'That' is a complementiser in 'The student said that he would come' and in OP's example. Not a classic conjunction. 'The student said' / They may just find out' are not independent clauses (though doubtless are used as standalone fragments).

Comment: @StuartF An answer to your comment is now in the post.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth An answer to your comment is now in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Some English teachers like to explain that commas indicate where to take a breath, but that is an oversimplification.  English prose does not make any indications of how something should be read out loud.  However, there are forms of poetry and music that do indicate meter and where to breathe.

In this case, although there is one comma, I would not take a breath during this sentence.  It is long enough that I would be concerned with my audience becoming confused that I am starting a new thought or sentence by taking a breath.

Comment: If I wanted the pauses (for dramatic emphasis, say) after 'that' and 'wrong', I would signal this by using commas. See [Usage of brackets / parentheses etc {with parentheticals}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100603/usage-of-brackets-parentheses-etc/100623#100623).

Comment: That sentence is much too long to speak without a breath.